# Call an array entry with a variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Is it possible to call an array entry with a variable?

```
$files = array('img/1.jpg','img/2.jpg','img/3.jpg');
$slot=0;
$fullpath = 'img/4.jpg'; //In the original Programm this path is generated
$files[$slot] = $fullpath;
```

When i try this code it doesnt work.

Comment: $fullpath is not defined in the snippet, I guess you wanted to do `$fullpath = realpath($files[$slot]);`

Comment: Do it like $fullpath = $files[$slot];

Comment: Sorry this is only a Fragment of the Code. Let me edit it, so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure it's working fine.

```
<?php
$files = array('img/1.jpg','img/2.jpg','img/3.jpg');
$slot=0;
$files[$slot] = '';
array_push($files ,$fullpath);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$files = array('img/1.jpg','img/2.jpg','img/3.jpg');
$slot=0;
$fullpath = $files[$slot];
```

And, add new values:

```
$new_value = 'img/4.jpg';
$files[] = $new_value; //or $files[] = 'img/4.jpg';
```

Replace $files[$slot]

```
$fullpath = 'img/4.jpg';
$files[$slot] = $fullpath;
```

Comment: But with this Solution the $fullpath variable gets the Value of the $files[0]

Comment: you edit your post.. so, you need replace value of $files[0] with $fullpath value o $fullpath variable?

Comment: or you need get index in array with value $fullpath?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$files = array('img/1.jpg','img/2.jpg','img/3.jpg');
$slot = 0;
if(isset($files[$slot]))
{
   $fullpath = realpath($files[$slot]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> switch your variable for the assignment.

```
$files[$slot] = $fullpath; to  $fullpath = $files[$slot];
```

cause you are assigning a value to your `$fullpath` variable.